# CSS full height fixed columns in a floated layout

Tags: css

Here is the JSFiddle example of how my layout is: http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/13/

I want to emulate the look of a desktop application like Outlook or Photoshop for example where the left and right side columns are fixed and occupy the full height of the screen.

In my application there is a header at the top of the page. So I want my header and sidebars to be fixed and not move when the user scrolls. Only the `#content` area should move.

Is this too big a task to ask on here I don't know. I'm using CSS2 only (can't use CSS3 yet).

Comment: You can use `position:fixed;` to make it work

Comment: Here is a fiddle to show how this is accomplished, http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/16/show/. (remove show in url to see code)

Comment: @JoshPowell wow that's awesome, how come you didn't post it as an answer?

Comment: @volumeone The answer provided is mostly the same, mine only included better formatting/styles. If you want I can post it but I felt it was not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:fixed;` to make it work

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
#aside-left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
}
#content{
    margin:0 130px;
    margin-top:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#aside-right {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    right:20px
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/qKP2v/14/)

Comment: thank you for the solution. can you suggest how to make the side columns stretch all the way down to the bottom of the browser window? i.e. full height